# Position pop up div where user is looking

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have a pop up div working on click. I need to have the pop up appear in the browser where the user is looking. Right now on short pages the pop up div is no where to be found and on long pages you have to scroll way down to even see the pop up.

So far I have tried a couple different things in my popUpDiv with no luck.

```
margin: 30px auto 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;



 margin-left: -155px;
    margin-top: -700px;
```

Here is my css:

```
/*STYLES FOR CSS POPUP*/
#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
}
#popUpDiv {
    padding: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    height:255px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    z-index: 9002;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: -155px;
    margin-top: -700px;
}
#popUpDiv a {position:relative; top:0px; right:10px}
/*END CSS POPUP*/
```

Here is what I have in my php file:

```
<!--POPUP--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/css-pop.js"></script>

    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;">
    </div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">


        Pop Up content Here


    </div>
<!-- / POPUP-->
```

Comment: Until you provide a position for popUpDiv, it will be rendered according to its position in the DOM.  Try giving it a top: or left: style.  Also, you may use the click event position to set the position of the new div if you want it to be where the user is pointing (not looking, since there is no way to check where the user is looking ;) )

Comment: @Steve H. I'll go ahead and try to give it a top: or left: style. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than a few ways to do what you're trying to do in jscript, but the cadillac way to do it might be modal popups: http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-modal-popups/ .

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems like a much simpler way to get a pop up. Now I just have to figure out how to incorporate it into my current page.

Comment: I believe you download and add modal.css to your website's css directory then take a look at popup form #1 & form #2 in index.html in the example.  It's not too bad.  Somebody here suggested using cursor coordinates, that would put it exactly where the user is browsing, but personally I don't appreciate that, it interrupts the browsing experience when I need to close that window.  A better way to do it is hover over popups that close when i hover off (like what happens when you scroll over a movie on netflix).

Comment: I got it all working and loved it, but for some reason it made all of my embedded videos not show up. It was just dead space where the video usually is. Weird I know, I'm going to try and figure out what is causing the conflict later today. Thank you for showing me this, I had never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

Position: fixed will solve your problem.  Your use of position: absolute is causing all the drama.

```
#popUpDiv {
    padding: 40px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    height:255px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    z-index: 9002;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```